# How to dynamically assign id value to a jquery function of getting backgroundImage url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div having a background image , 
i have a jquery function which get the name of  the background image URL..

```js
var name=image;

var url=$("#"+name+"").css("background-image");

console.log(url);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid black; background-image: url(images2/https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300)">
```

My problem is that i want to give the id to jquery function dynamically from a variable, but when i try it is not possible...

I have tried to change the code to

> var url=$("#"+name+"").css("background-image");

but not working

How to so solve this? 
I want the id name to inserted dynamically?

Comment: set `var name='image';` like this.

Comment: try this:
var name="image";
var url=$("#"+name).css("background-image");

Comment: @kaushal-shah  the image will be comming dynamically in my situation...then how can i put it in 'image', then it will be static know

Comment: if `image` is dynamic then first you need to assing value in `image` variable.

Comment: @shehroz-altaf  the varible image is dynamic in my case i cant put in inverted commas

Comment: i hope you have to  pass image as variable.

Comment: @devsi-odedra please show an example

Comment: can you brief your problem pls

Comment: when does your function triggers? can you send the triggered function code

Comment: show the elements having dynamic ids, so we know how to assignit dynamically.

Comment: @DevsiOdedra So you have to put common class for that elements. to get the dynamic IDs

Comment: @obito-uchiha  in my progam i get the id name(say image) dynamically using some function an the will change the next time,  Im trying the get thebackgroudImage url of using that changing varible here it is name

Comment: @kaushalshah ya right.

Comment: @devmaddy so when you got that dynamic name of id, then pass it to `name` and it will work.

Comment: @devsi-odedra  can yoy show in code it will be helpful

Comment: This is trivial syntax error. There isn't any reasonable programming problem here

Comment: please post your expected result @kaushalshah

Comment: @udo-e can you understand the scenario? or need explanation

Comment: @devmaddy see my answer with update

Comment: @devmaddy, does your question still require an answer after you correct the syntax error - `var name='image';`? If it does, edit your post and correct it right away. I hope you also find another problem area to make your question relevant.

Comment: @devsi-odedra  please see my opinion under your code

Comment: @udo-e i understand brother it will work when i change the code the way 'image' but my case is different...please try to look what im a asking for

Answer (score 1):

`image` is not variable its value so put inside quote

```js
var name=getDynamicID();

var url=$("#"+name).css("background-image");

console.log(url);


function getDynamicID(){

 return 'image';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid black; background-image: url(images2/https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300)">
```

Comment: it great this could get me half way

Comment: is there a way i can make that return 'image';   image changeable

Comment: you can select id with `attr` of any element

Comment: @devmaddy can you show me your `html` structure so i can tell that how can you get dynamically `image`

Comment: $( function() {
  
  $( dropnameset ).draggable({ revert: 'invalid' });
  $( "#box"+(dragitemindex++) ).droppable(
  
  
  {
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
      var droppableId = $(this).attr("id"); 

     var bg=$("#"+droppableId+"").css('background-image');     here droppableid is image i used

Comment: here   is the main function portion  which i tried to demonstrate using example

Comment: create one fidle with your entire code with all html and js code with included cdn. in above code you have missing some js code and where is `#box` in html ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about your question, but you can get the image URL in this way

```js
function geturl(image)
{
    var name=image;
    var url=$("#"+name).css("background-image");
    console.log(url.split('(')[1].split('"')[1]);

}

geturl('image1')   //Your Dynamic Image ID's
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="image" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid black; background-image: url(images2/https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300)">

<div id="image1" style=" width: 100px; height: 100px; border: 2px solid black; background-image: url(images2/https://picsum1.photo1s/id1/2317/2001/3001)">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divId = $("div")[0].getAttribute("id");
console.log(divId);
```

Then you can assign this id to your name variable.
But this is only for first div.
You can change the index or loop through all divs.